# jQuery accordion menu: Setting active class

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="highmenu">Menu1</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li class="submenulink">Menu1Link1</li>
            <li class="submenulink">Menu1Link2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="highmenu">Menu2</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li class="submenulink">Menu2Link1</li>
            <li class="submenulink">Menu2Link2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the jQuery script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $("#menu ul").hide();
    $("#menu a[href='" + pathname + "']").parents(".sub").show();
    $("#menu li a").click(function() {
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is("ul")) && (checkElement.is(":visible"))) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $("#menu ul:visible").slideUp("normal");
            checkElement.slideDown("normal");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

What I would like to have is that when particular sub is open, the corresponding highmenu will be set to `highmenu active` class and when sub is hidden, the active class will be removed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Every time you click on a link remove all active class from all links then apply it to only the appropriate one:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$("#menu ul").hide();
$("#menu a[href='" + pathname + "']").parents(".sub").show();
$("#menu li a").click(function() {

    $("#menu li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if ((checkElement.is("ul")) && (checkElement.is(":visible"))) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $("#menu ul:visible").slideUp("normal");
        checkElement.slideDown("normal");
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jKGNA/

Comment: Thanks! It works, but when I click one of the sublinks, the `highmenu active` is no longer active. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. By sublinks do you mean the elements with class "submenulink" (such as Menu1Link1)? Have you changed the html at all to include anchor tags in the submenu (such as <li class="submenulink"><a href="blah">Menu1Link2</a></li>)?

Comment: If so the event handler may be fired by clicking on non-top-level menu items. Try changing the selectors in line 4 and 6 (my example) to $("a.highmenu").